# A k-1 form on a compact, orientable, k dimensional manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Hi I am stuck on the following problem: Let $M$ be a $k$-dimensional, orientable, compact manifold. Without using directly Stokes theorem, show that for every differentiable $k-1$ form $\omega$
$$\int_{M}d\omega=0$$
Conclude that if M is additionally connected, $d\omega$ admits a zero in $M$.
First I am wondering about the phrasing "not using directly Stokes", second we got also an hint which is stated the following: $M$ is the union of sets $G_1$ and $G_2$ with smooth boundary, where the boundaries seen as sets are the same. I am really confused about this tip, because I don't see how this decomposition could possibly work out in general. Is somebody able to help me please?

Comment: did you intend to write "$=0$"?

Comment: Where did you find that problem and that hint?

Comment: Yes I intended to write =0. And yeah it is in the Königsberger Analysis 2.

Comment: In questions like "show without using theorem A" We always can use the proof of theorem A directly to solve the problem.

Comment: Probably you can use a partition of unity $(\phi _i)$such that $\Sigma \phi _i=1$ and $\phi _i$ has support in a chart. This reduces the problem to a form in $\bf R^n$ with support in $]-1,1[^n$, which is $O$ outside this set. For such a form it is easy to compute the integral (by Fubini) and find $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Not using directly Stokes" probably means that you're supposed to use a different argument than:
$$
\int_Md\omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega = \int_\emptyset \omega=0.
$$
I interpret it as okay to use Stokes on $G_1$ and $G_2$ though. You can get $G_1$ as a smoothly embedded closed ball, and $G_2$ as the compliment of the interior of $G_1$.